# How to access the map returned by IParameterValues::getParameterValues()?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I declared a command and a commandParameter for this command. I specified the "values" of this commandParameter as a class implemented by myself. The implementation of this class is below,

```
public class ParameterValues implements IParameterValues {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Double> getParameterValues() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, Double> values = new HashMap<String, Double>(2);
        values.put("testParam", 1.1239);
        values.put("AnotherTest", 4.1239);
        return values;      
    }

}
```

The implementation of the handler of this command is blow,

```
public class testHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {
    private static String PARAMETER_ID = "my.parameter1";

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        String value = event.getParameter(PARAMETER_ID);    
        MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event),
                "Test", "Parameter ID: " + PARAMETER_ID + "\nValue: " + value);

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, I contribute the command to a menu,

```
 <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="my.edit"
               label="Edit">
            <command
                  commandId="myCommand.test"
                  label="Test1">
               <parameter
                     name="my.parameter1"
                     value="testParam">
               </parameter>
            </command>
```

Since I specified a "values" class for the commandParater, I expect when the menu is clicked, this code line "String value = event.getParameter(PARAMETER_ID);" in the handler class returns 1.1239 instead of "testParam".
But, I still see that code line returns "testParam".

What's the problem?  How could I access the map returned by getParameterValues()?

By the way, following menu declaration still works even I don't define "ppp" in the map.

```
 <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="my.edit"
               label="Edit">
            <command
                  commandId="myCommand.test"
                  label="Test1">
               <parameter
                     name="my.parameter1"
                     value="ppp">
               </parameter>
            </command>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc, `org.eclipse.core.commands.IParameterValues.getParameterValues()` "Returns a map keyed by externalized names for parameter values. These names should be human-readable, and are generally for display to the user in a user interface of some sort. The values should be actual values that will be interpreted by the handler for the command."

This interface is used to provide translatable names for command parameters.  So that "Show View (Package Explorer)" can be displayed in the Keys preference page instead of "Show View (org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer)"

But `org.eclipse.ui.menus` definitions must contain the parameter value as opposed to a translatable name.

You can define the parameter type and `AbstractParameterValueConverter` in the command definition if you want to process the string parameters and turn them into various objects.